# CompletableFuture<T> class: join() vs get()

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

What is the difference between the `get()` and `join()` methods of the `CompletableFuture<T>` class?

Below is the my code:

```
List<String> process() {

    List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("Msg1", "Msg2", "Msg3", "Msg4", "Msg5", "Msg6", "Msg7", "Msg8", "Msg9",
            "Msg10", "Msg11", "Msg12");
    MessageService messageService = new MessageService();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    List<String> mapResult = new ArrayList<>();

    CompletableFuture<?>[] fanoutRequestList = new CompletableFuture[messages.size()];
    int count = 0;
    for (String msg : messages) {
        CompletableFuture<?> future = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> messageService.sendNotification(msg), executor).exceptionally(ex -> "Error")
                .thenAccept(mapResult::add);

        fanoutRequestList[count++] = future;
    }

    try {
        CompletableFuture.allOf(fanoutRequestList).get();
      //CompletableFuture.allOf(fanoutRequestList).join();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mapResult.stream().filter(s -> !s.equalsIgnoreCase("Error")).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I have tried with both methods but I see no difference in result.

Comment: `get()` requires you to catch checked exceptions. You should notice the difference when you change from `get()` to `join()`, as you will imediately get a compiler error saying that neither `InterruptedException` nor `ExecutionException` are thrown in the `try` block.

Comment: @holi-java: `join()` can not get interrupted.

Comment: @Holger yes, sir. I found I can't interrupt the task.

Comment: @Holger, Thank you for reply and you are correct, get expects checked exception and join method not. But both are waiting for complete the all the future and I would like know whcih one I should use and why?

Comment: Well `get` exists, because `CompletableFuture` implements the `Future` interface which mandates it. `join()` most likely has been introduced, to avoid needing to catch checked exceptions in lambda expressions when combining futures. In all other use cases, feel free to use whatever you prefer.

Comment: Does it really make sense to use join or get as both block on the thread. Can't we instead make this asynchronous by using other composition methods to create a chain of asynchronous functions.ofvourse it depends on functionality. But in case of e.g. a service method in spring called by controller method returning completeable future it makes more sense to not call get or join in service method at all .does it?

Answer (score 196):

The only difference is how methods throw exceptions. `get()` is declared in `Future` interface as:

```
V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException;
```

The exceptions are both **checked** exceptions which means they need to be handled in your code. As you can see in your code, an automatic code generator in your IDE asked to create try-catch block on your behalf.

```
try {
  CompletableFuture.allOf(fanoutRequestList).get() 
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The `join()` method doesn't throw **checked** exceptions.

```
public T join()
```

Instead it throws **unchecked** `CompletionException`. So you do not need a try-catch block and instead you can fully harness `exceptionally()` method when using the disscused `List<String> process` function

```
CompletableFuture<List<String>> cf = CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(this::process)
    .exceptionally(this::getFallbackListOfStrings) // Here you can catch e.g. {@code join}'s CompletionException
    .thenAccept(this::processFurther);
```

You can find both `get()` and `join()` implementation [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java).

Comment: The part about `exceptionally()` is a bit distracting because it isn't relevant, as `exceptionally(…)` can be used with either `get()` or with `join()`. Perhaps you were trying to add additional commentary that `exceptionally()` is a different approach for handling `CompletableFuture` entirely; if so, it might help to clarify this and set it apart from the main answer. Nevertheless, there are even addition approaches to error handling with `CompletableFuture`, I'm not sure arbitrarily listing one of them really adds to the answer.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to the answer provided by Dawid, the get method is available in two flavors:

```
get()
get(Long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit)
```

The second **get** takes wait time as an argument and waits for at most the provided wait time.

```
try {
    System.out.println(cf.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can refer to [this documentation](https://tedblob.com/completablefuture-join-vs-get/) for more information.

1. join() is defined in CompletableFuture whereas get() comes from interface Future
2. join() throws unchecked exception whereas get() throws checked exceptions
3. You can interrupt get() and then throws an InterruptedException
4. get() method allows to specify the maximum wait time

Comment: This is a good answer. While it's mostly recommended to use join one limitation of join is that you can't set timeout. get helps overcome this limitation.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers talk about "one of the methods uses checked exceptions; the other does not", which is true, but misses some of the subtleties.

Based upon reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), let me try to break it down succinctly:

- If the underlying task producing the value throws an exception, both [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get()) and [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()) will throw a "wrapper exception" containing the thrown exception. In the case of `get()`, the wrapper exception will be an `ExecutionException`, which is a checked exception; in the case of `join()`, it will be a `CompletionException`, which is an unchecked exception. In either case, the wrapped exception (originating in the underlying task) will be the same.
- It appears the `join()` *cannot* throw an `InterruptedException`; see [CompletableFuture join vs get differences](https://tedblob.com/completablefuture-join-vs-get/) for sample code.
- Either method can throw a `CancellationException`.

To summarize, `join()` is a "simplified" form of `get()` that doesn't throw `InterruptedException`, and returns its value in an unchecked `CompletionException`. If you use instead `get()`, you'll be forced not only to catch an `ExecutionException` (which will contain the same wrapped exception as `CompletionException` would), but also catch `InterruptedException`.